# Drawing on UIImage and save original size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics

I need to draw lines on UIImage (image load from file system) and save it, but I have a problem. When I trying to save context to file, saved image have size equal imageView size (If I set "tempImageView.frame.size" to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and draw(in:)). If I change "size" in code and set tempImageView.image?.size saved image size is OK, but drawing is not work good (lines draw with offset, and lines view badly)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.swiped = false
    if let touch = touches.first {


        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)

        print(lastPoint)

    }
}

func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {


    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((tempImageView.image?.size)!, false, scale)

  let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: (tempImageView.image?.size)!))

    //let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    print("context size = \(context)")
    print("fromPoint = \(fromPoint), toPoint = \(toPoint)")
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y:fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y:toPoint.y))

    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(5)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor)
    context?.strokePath()

    tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    self.newImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint
        print(lastPoint)

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the `UIImage` size for the context, and scale *up* the line drawn to that? I pretty much do that to create a user-defined mask.

Comment: Do you mean multiply points at scale or other value? I tried do it, but I don't have good result. Lines are still offsets. I don't understand how to use scale value? Can you present some example?